# Create Cylinder to 6 Sided to Cylinder Transition Topolgy

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to create a mesh that smoothly transitions from a cylinder to a hexagonal body.
I have create the mesh as per attached pictures however when I apply the 'Subdivision' Modifier it doesn't look right because the transitions are very sharp.
Any advise about how to improve the mesh?
[image]
[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try another topology:

- First bevel your hexagonal shape:

[image]

- Extrude, then right click > LoopTools > Circle:

[image]

- Rearrange the topology a bit:

[image]

Comment: This helps, many thanks!